# renderInContext in uiwebview change my contentSize

Tags: ios, uiwebview, render

Is anyone have some trouble with renderInContext ?

Because i'm trying to render a UIWebView, but the call to renderInContext modify my UIWebView contentSize !

Here is my code :

```
-(void)render
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.bounds.size); 
    // webview.scrollView.contentSize.width = 5120.0
    [webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
    // webview.scrollView.contentSize.width = 6400.0
    renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem.Have you found the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

I get the error: Instance method '-renderInContext:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

**Update:**

Link to the QuartzCore.framework, and #import  into your class.

Comment: Duh... I forgot to import QuartzCore.framework and also import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in my header.